# Finding the least number of equations for which that $S-1$ is a component.

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Let $S=\sum w$, summed over all words $w=\{x,y\}$ with the same number of $x$'s and $y$'s.  Let $\phi$ be the abelianization operator.  We know that

$$\phi(S)=\sum_{n\geq1}{2n\choose n}x^ny^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4xy}}$$

My question here is:  what is the least number of equations in a proper algebraic system for which that $S-1$ is a component?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "proper algebraic system" or by a "component" of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Let $Q$ be series:  $Q=1+xQyQ+yQxQ$, and therefore $Q$ is algebraic.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!